# Nethereum - Contract not storing passed variables when deployed

Tags: contract-development, nethereum

I know it's not a problem with the contract because when I deploy using Etherem Wallet, all the variables are stored as expected. I'm assuming it's how I pass in the parameters using Nethereum sdk.

.Net code:

```
transactionHash = await web3.Eth.DeployContract.SendRequestAsync(byteCode,senderAddress, new HexBigInteger(900000), new object[] { sd.docTitle,sd.datetimestamp, sd.author });
```

Through debugging I know the sd.docTitle, sd.datetimestamp, and sd.author is not null and is a type string when passing.

Constructor in contract:

```
/* this runs when the contract is executed */
function DocumentValidity(string _docTitle, string _dateTimeStamp,string _author) public {
    docTitle = _docTitle;
    DateTimeStamp = _dateTimeStamp;
    author=_author;
}
```

Any Ideas as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 2):

Fixed it! Forgot to add a variable for returning.
Changed the get methods to `return (string s)`, before it was `constant return (string)`. So,

```
function DocumentTitle() constant returns (string) {
    return docTitle;
}
```

now looks like

```
function DocumentTitle() returns (string s) {
    return docTitle;
}
```

Simple right ?...

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to pass the way you are passing in the parameters at the time of deploying contract.

Once you get the successful receipt  .
do this steps :-

1. get the contract Address from the receipt.
2. call your function.

3.Now you can send your parameters by using transaction async.

check below code:-

```
  var contract = web3.Eth.GetContract(abi, contractAdd);

  var setData = contract.GetFunction("yourFunctionName");

  var hash = await setData.SendTransactionAsync(senderAddress, new 
  HexBigInteger("100000"), null,_docTitle,_dateTimeStamp,_author);
```